# Why is it not a good idea to introduce an instance variable for the area? And how do you fix it?

Tags: java

```
public class Square {
    private int sideLength;
    private int area;     // Not a good idea

    public Square(int length) {
        sideLength = length; 
    }

    public int getArea() {
        area = sideLength * sideLength;
        return area; 
    }
}
```

Why is it not a good idea to introduce an instance variable for the area? And how do you fix it, thanks

Comment: Code formatting matters -- please learn it and apply it.

Comment: Well, what do you think is the answer to your homework question?

Comment: It's sort of like asking for my birth date AND my age - it is really unnecessary to ask for age when you can compute it based off my birth date.

Comment: Per the posted code it would be bad practice not to have just area variable that is calculated in the constructor since the class only has `getArea` method. I kind of understand the intention of showing example of derived value here but the example chosen is not the best one.

Answer (score 3):

Because for a square, `area` is entirely determined by `sideLength`. There is no need for it when you can simply say

```
public int getArea() {
    return sideLength * sideLength; 
}
```

and eliminate `area` entirely.

P.S. There is a valid use case for storing a redundant private variable, specifically when calculating it is an expensive operation and you only want to do it when needed. This is called caching. But the multiplication operation is so cheap that there is no reason to do it in your case—and anyway, you are calculating `area` every time `getArea()` is called, so there would be no performance benefit even if the calculation were costly.

Answer (score 2):

You are calculating the area each time you call 'getArea()' anyway. So you should either just calculate and return it or calculate it in your constructor and just return it on method call.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a good idea because there is no point in storing it. You can always calculate it again (if the calculation process would be very time consuming you should store it).
You could do:

```
public class Square {
    private int sideLength;

    public Square(int length) {
        sideLength = length;
    }

    public int getArea() {
        int area = sideLength * sideLength;
        return area;
    }
}
```

and use a local variable instead. Or even shorter:

```
...
public int getArea() {
    return sideLength * sideLength;
}
...
```

Comment: Could whoever downvoted me explain why? Or correct what I have written and is wrong in their opinion?